# How could I return a number based on phase starts and completions for each group?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have projects with starts and completions for multiple phases.  I like the query to return the current phase number that the project is currently in based on having a start date but no completion date.  If all phases are complete (all have completion dates) then it should return 4.  Another assumption is all phases are to be completed in order starting with phase 1.

```
PRJ   Start1   Complete1   Start2    Complete2   Start3    Complete3
A    3/1/2019  3/5/2019   3/6/2019   3/9/2019   3/9/2019
B    2/2/2019
C    4/1/2019  4/2/2019   4/13/2019
D    3/2/2019  4/5/2019   4/6/2019   4/7/2019   5/9/2019   6/20/2019

Desired:
PRJ   Current_Phase
A           3
B           1
C           2
D           4
```

I'm not sure how to begin.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the first `null` value.  Use `switch()`:

```
select t.*,
       switch(complete1 is null, 1,
              complete2 is null, 2,
              complete3 is null, 3,
              1=1, 4
             ) as current_phase
from t;
```